# Swift Dictionary: How to merge values in dictionary contains similar keys

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
var dict1 = [2019 : [J,F,M], 2019 : [J,S,O],2018 : [J,F,M], 2018 : [J,S,O]]
```

expected output:

```
var dict1 = [2019 : [J,F,M,S,O], 2018 : [J,F,M,S,O]]
```

I want to merge the unique values in a dictionary contains duplicate keys.

Comment: *“I have a dictionary as follows ...”* – Really? A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: @MartinR It is possible to have a dictionary with duplicate keys. Server is returning as above

Comment: It seems JSON string not a swift dictionary possibly.

Comment: Then it is not a dictionary. Could you post a string version of your server response? Is it json or something else?

Comment: Then your real problem is that you have a JSON response containing a JSON dictionary with duplicate keys.

Comment: Though it's "possible" to make a string of JSON that contains a dictionary with colliding keys, such a dictionary wouldn't be valid according to the JSON spec, and wouldn't work in neither JavaScript, nor in Swift.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is already [merge function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127171-merge) that allows you to do whatever with the values you desire in your final (merged) dictionary:

```
mutating func merge<S>(_ other: S, uniquingKeysWith combine: (Value, Value) throws -> Value) rethrows where S : Sequence, S.Element == (Key, Value)
```

Within closure you will want to parse both value arrays and make your desired array from them for every key.

Comment: That won't help here because there is no way of parsing the JSON response with duplicate keys into a Swift dictionary in the first place.